# How to implement multiple Dropbox Javascript Choosers on a page?

Tags: javascript, api, dropbox

Dropbox's [official page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js) teaches how to implement a single chooser, but doesn't teach how to implement multiple choosers on a page.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The `createChooseButton` method can be used multiple times to create multiple Chooser buttons that you can put wherever you want. E.g.:

```
        var button = Dropbox.createChooseButton(options);
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(button);

        var button2 = Dropbox.createChooseButton(options2);
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(button2);
```